# How to do this css3 kind of animation like google doing for its official blog

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am currently working on wordpress website, basically a blog.
The client request some simple clean animation on the header section like google doing on
http://googleblog.blogspot.in/

I know google using css3 transform & following properties for it
scale,translate & timing function

Can anybody tell me how can i create something like that 
basically i am unable to understand the logic written for mouse movement & the bubbles moving path(the path along which they move it look like they are not using cubic bezier curve )

So please if anybody know how its going please add your thoughts.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is not made with CSS, as -for one- it responds to mouse movement. It is probably made with javascript.

As for that, a simple answer to 'how do I make this' cannot be given for it's most likely quite an extensive script.

Comment: Its animating with help of javascript but if you see in firebug they are using webkit-transform : translate(x,y) property which is css3

Comment: It's animating with javascript, with some additional css for completion. Without the css it would probably look a little different, but it would still be functional. It's the javascript that creates the mouse interaction and animations.